# assignment to an array of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x = 0;
}

std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>, 10> Arr;

// Arr[0] = ?
```

What is the syntax to assign an object to such an array? [My reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Those declarations are not equivalent.

Comment: `Arr1[0].reset(new MyStruct)`?

Comment: @FeiXiang and in C++14 and later, prefer `std::make_unique()` instead: `Arr1[0] = std::make_unique<MyStruct>();`

Comment: You are declaring an array of unique pointers each of which points to an instance of MyStruct. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @doug Yes. that's what I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by  Fei Xiang:

```
Arr[0].reset(new MyStruct);
```

Answered by Remy Lebeau:

```
Arr[0] = std::make_unique<MyStruct>(); // Since C++14
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>, 10> Arr {
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>(),
  std::make_unique<MyStruct>()
};
```

To avoid the move assignment.